# matrix $Q$ that has orthonormal columns but $QQ^T \ne I $

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking to check if my solution is correct. I need to give an example of a matrix a matrix $Q$ that has orthonormal columns but $QQ^T \ne I $

My solution:

This matrix has to be non-square. $Q^TQ=I $, so $Q^T = Q^{-1}$ and $QQ^T = I$. An example would be $(1,0)^T$

Just looking to see if this logic is correct

Comment: So the matrix $Q$ is of any size? If so, then the example $Q=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ certainly works. However, I'm confused why you have $Q^T=Q^{-1}$ after you said the matrix must be non-square. If it is non-square, it cannot have an inverse (discounting "left" and "right" inverses).

Comment: @ Dave so saying This matrix has to be non-square. $Q^TQ=I $ is enough?

Comment: So your task is to find a matrix of any size, $Q$, with orthonormal columns, which does not satisfy $QQ^T=I$? If I am understanding this correctly, then your choice of example, $Q=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, is a very good example (and completes your task). Your assumption that it must be non-square is also necessary, because if $Q$ is square, then $Q$ is unitary, so it does satisfy $QQ^T=I$.

Comment: @Dave thanks for your input